# Internet connection detection in android in an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have this class that I'm using for detecting in every Activity if there is internet connection. My problem is that I don't want to loop every time over the AsyncTask , because I got a problem in my progressDialog when I change the context. This is my class:

public class InternetConnection {

```
public Boolean isInternetPresent;
public ConnectionDetector cd;   
public Context con;
public ProgressDialog progressBar;

public InternetConnection () {
    this.isInternetPresent = false;
}

public void hay_internet(){

    new Async().execute();

}

public void cambiar_context(Context c) {
    this.con = c;
    this.cd = new ConnectionDetector(c);
    progressBar=new ProgressDialog(con);
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.setMessage("Buscando conexión de internet");
    progressBar.setTitle("Conectando ...");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
}

class Async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

         if(!isInternetPresent) {                
             progressBar.show();
        }
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        while(!isInternetPresent){
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        progressBar.dismiss();
        new Async().execute(); 
     }
}
```

}

How can I fix this loop, so I can stop calling everytime the AsyncTask.

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges

Comment: Android broadcasts events when the device's connectivity changes. You should listen to them. Read this: [http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Comment: Here is an example that I found few days ago : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the ConnectivityManager to check if there is a network connection available. 
for  example i use this method in my apps:

```
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
           ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
           NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
           return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

that method is to check if there is a connection available.
if you want to get notified when the connection status changes (for example wifi is lost) you should use a broadcast receiver.

```
 public class NetworkStateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (info.isConnected()) {
                // you got a connection! tell your user!
            } 
        } 
    }
  }
```

and you need to register this broadcast receiver in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.NetworkStateChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

best is you check out the official android example:
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: Should I write this in every Activity? It's that I want to detect in any moment that I have lost connection to Internet and notify the user that there isn't a connection and he wouldn't be capable of doing anything, until there is Internet.

Comment: @varjo - awesome explanation mate, straight to the point. +1. Thanks. :) I believe the broadcast will be called any point in time when the network status changes, ryt. Please correct me I am wrong.